# Setting for tracking a privilege / tag badge overlaps tracker

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

**MacOS**: 10.12.5
**Safari**: 10.1.1 (12603.2.4)

**Windows**: 10.1703.15063.296
**Opera**: 45.0.2552.881 32-bit

**Windows**: 10.1703.15063.296
**Chrome**: 58.0.3029.110 64-bit

**Windows**: 10.1703.15063.296
**Internet Explorer**: 11.296.15063.0

**Windows**: 10.1703.15063.296
**Edge**: 40.15063.0.0

**Windows Mobile**: 10.0.15063.297
**Edge**: 40.15063.297.0 (In full-site mode)

**iOS**: 10.3.2
**Safari**: 10.0 (In full-site mode)

I've confirmed on all the environments above. Another user has confirmed on environments below:

**Windows**: 10.1607.14393.1198
**Firefox**: 53.0.3 64-bit

**Windows**: 10.1607.14393.1198
**Chrome**: 58.0.3029.110 64-bit

**Android**: 6.0 24.231.16.clark_reteu.reteu.en.EU.retgb (Moto X Style)
**Firefox**: 53.0.2

Hard to explain, but a picture is worth a thousand words. Look under the reputation graph, CSS strikes again and the little cog (and the associated menu) is misplaced:

[image: Overlap]

[image]

Comment: I don't debug CSS, but I believe browser+version might be relevant here ;-)

Comment: FWIW, no repro on my mobile Chrome browser.

Comment: @Mat'sMug You're not wrong about the browser / OS version, totally forgot to post that.

Comment: no repo on firefox 53.0.3 either

Comment: Repo Firefox 53.0.3 64-bit & Chrome 58.0.3029.110 64-bit Windows 10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The change that caused this bug has been reverted and will be fixed in the next build. Thanks for reporting!

Comment: No, thank you! I honestly don't know why I saw it, I was on that page for a completely unrelated reason and it caught my eye.